# Use special character in emacs init file with "global-set-key"

Tags: key-bindings, init-file

I want to be able to automatically insert pre-defined strings when pressing a certain keybinding. Currently this is being done with the following code snippet:

```
;;;;; Personal keybindings                                                
(global-set-key [f6] "\autocite[--]{}")
```

The problem is, that this does not work (the one in the example). Instead, 
Emacs will tell me "After 0 kbd macro iterations: Quit" which does not show up, when just doing the string without the "\". So how could I fix this and enter pre-defined strings which include special character such as "\"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double backslashes within strings:

```
(global-set-key [f6] "\\autocite[--]{}")
```

A more reliable binding uses the `insert` function explicitly:

```
(global-set-key [f6] #'(lambda ()
                         (interactive)
                         (insert "\\autocite[--]{}")))
```

and you'll probably want to move point within the braces:

```
(global-set-key [f6] #'(lambda ()
                         (interactive)
                         (insert "\\autocite[--]{}")
                         (forward-char -1)))
```

Comment: @jch I would prefer defining the interactive function first and then binding a key to that function name.